# tensorflow configure error: Unexpected error reading .blazerc file '%workspace%/.tf_configure.bazelrc'

Tags: tensorflow, config

I use ubuntu 14.04, cuda 8.0 cudnn 5.1
when I config tensorflow, some errors show as follow:

Unexpected error reading `.blazerc file '%workspace%/.tf_configure.bazelrc'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `.bazelrc` to replace `%workspace%` with the path to `.tf_configure.bazelrc`.